# Login through Twitter and Google Plus in Appcelerator Studio

Tags: twitter, titanium, google-plus, appcelerator

It been two days I'm working with twitter and google plus Signup/Signin but unfortunately unable to hit it.

For twitter, I tried Aaron K Saunders's test app https://github.com/aaronksaunders/test_social. It says "You've granted access to your app. Next, return to your app and enter this PIN (XXXXXXX) to complete authentication process". What really is that??? I'm confused in it.

For google plus, I tried Google Auth for Titanium test app https://github.com/ejci/Google-Auth-for-Titanium. But it shows simple white screen.

I'm stuck into both of these. Can anyone please help. I'd be grateful.

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you posted this issue on Test Social's GitHub page? Here's what I had to do to get Twitter working on Android - Test Social still works as intended on iOS.

"I have the same issue (Android only, iOS still works as before). This is an issue with Android, not this module. Here is how I go about fixing this on Android.

getHtml on the webView is returning null in Android, but again fine in iOS - Just putting this out there in case anybody runs into this error. Doesn't seem to be a fault of this module.

I modified the authorizeUICallback function inside Test Social:

```
function authorizeUICallback(e) {

 var promptView = Ti.UI.createView({
        width:'30%',
        height:'10%',
        layout: "vertical",
        backgroundColor:'black',
        bottom:"20%"
    }),
    pinField = Ti.UI.createTextField({
        width: Ti.UI.FILL,
        height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
        hintText: 'Enter PIN'
    }),
    pinButton = Ti.UI.createButton({
        width: Ti.UI.SIZE,
        height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
        title: "Authorize"
    });

promptView.add(pinField);
promptView.add(pinButton);
view.add(promptView);

pinButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (!pinField.value) {
        alert('No PIN found');
    } else {
        pin = pinField.value;
        response = 1;
       response ? ( pin = pinField.value, /*pin = response.split("<code>")[1].split("</code>")[0]*/ destroyAuthorizeUI(), receivePinCallback()) : (loadingView && loadingView.hide(), loadingContainer && loadingContainer.hide(), webView && webView.show()), loading = !1, clearInterval(intervalID), estimates[estimateID] = (new Date).getTime() - startTime, Ti.App.Properties.setString("Social-LoadingEstimates", JSON.stringify(estimates));
    }
});
}
```

There was another issue created on the GitHub page and they haven't found a solution either. This seems to be the only way to get Twitter to work with Test Social (or the ONLY way I've found to get it to work with Appcelerator at all).

I can't help you with Google+ just yet. I'm looking to implement that later, but it's not super high on my priority list with their recent changes... Who knows how much longer people will be using it, but I digress... Are you getting any kind of error in the console when you get a 'white screen'?